# What to do about ListActivity/MapActivity when converting to Fragments using the compatibility library?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I'm converting an existing app to the Fragments API using the compatibility library. I've read that you're supposed to update classes that extend Activity to now use FragmentActivity. This is fine for most cases, but what about classes that extend ListActivity or MapActivity? What is the preferred way to handle this? I was hoping there was a ListFragmentActivity or something along those lines, but I don't see one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a ListFragment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html

For MapActivity, unfortunately you will need to continue to use that; there is no Fragment API for it.

Comment: Thanks, but ListFragment is not a FragmentActivity, so I'm having issues with my inheritance structure that expects a FragmentActivity. The more I work on this, the more it seems that it will need a total rewrite, not just updating class types and minor adjustments like Google claimed.

Comment: @CACuzcatlan: You are welcome to cite a link where "Google" "claimed" that all you would need is "just updating class types and minor adjustments". That being said, converting a `ListActivity` to a `ListFragment` is pretty simple, simpler than most activity->fragment migrations, IMHO.

Comment: Sorry, I exaggerated. I should say that was the impression I got.

Comment: In a ListFragment, I cannot use getActionBar(), but in a FragmentActivity well. What should I have to do?

Comment: The action bar is owned by the overall window.  Your fragments need to share it.  You just need to think about how you want to share it, and do whatever you decide.  If you need to directly get it from a fragment, use Fragment.getActivity().  If your fragment is putting actions in it, just populate the menus in your fragment like you normally would.  This code shows putting in a search widget: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LoaderCursor.html

Answer (score 12):

This is what I do when converting a ListActivity to the fragments API:

1. Replace `lv = getListView();` with `lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);`
2. Replace `setListAdapter(adapter);` with `lv.setAdapter(adapter);`
3. If you have overriden `onListItemClick()`, replace it with `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {...`
4. You'll have to set the empty view (that shows when there are no results) manually: `lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));`

   If I'm using CursorLoader, I normally put this in onLoadFinished():

   ```
   // if there are no results
   if (data.getCount() == 0) {
       // let the user know
       lv.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
   } else {
       // otherwise clear it, so it won't flash in between cursor loads
       lv.setEmptyView(null);
   }
   ```
5. Speaking of [cursor loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), I'll also convert the activity to use CursorLoader if it isn't already by that point

Comment: Would it suffice to just add a new method getListView() to the FragmentActivity that returned the ListView and then add another method setListAdapter(adapter) that called setAdapter(adapter) on that activity?

Comment: @Ankush that would work too.  You'll be searching the view hierarchy every time you call getListView() though, which is marginally less efficient.

Answer (score 8):

At least for the ListActivity You can change it to FragmentActivity (Still implementing OnItemCLickListener) and replace:

lv=getListView() to lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id)

and

setListAdapter(favAdapter) to lv.setAdapter(adapter)

Comment: If the ID of your ListView is `@android:id/list`, you can do this: `ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);`.  You'll also want to replace `onListItemClick()` with `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {...`

Comment: I commented this on the answer by @bmaupin as well, but can we just make methods "getListView()" that returns "(ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id)" and "setListAdapter(adapter)" that does "getListView().setAdapter(adapter)" to take care of those things or would that not work?

Comment: @Ankush that would work too.  You'll be searching the view hierarchy every time you call getListView() though, which is marginally less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to convert the `ListActivity` to a `FragmentActivity`.

1. Extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `ListActivity`
2. Create `res/layout/your_activity.xml` with an empty `ListView` with `android:id="@+id/your_activity_list_view"`
3. In the `onCreate` of your activity, `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);`
4. Also change the `onCreate` of your activity to explicitly retrieve the `ListView` you just inflated

.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_activity_list_view);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```