# Can I create Fragment ListActivity with compatibility package v4?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I've been trying to complete tutorial "Working with fragments" which was designed for android 3.0+

To acomplish that I'm using compatibility package v4 (since my API is 7). However I'm stuck on the lists. I couldn't find straight answer.

I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException. I inherited fragment class from FragmentActivity but what about my ListActivity? There is no such thing as FragmentListActivity and I think it keeps crashing at this.

Can I create Fragment ListActivity with compatibility package v4? Or it's not possible at all?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nope, doesn't exist. Stupid support library.

The solution is easy to create but tedious to maintain. Just copy the [native `ListActivity` class](https://raw.github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/d6c1919779acb042392615637b9007e0c4b89023/core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java) into your project, rename it "`FragmentListActivity`", and let it extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`. No other tweaks are required and the copy is easy. If you are uncertain you can [peak](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~pjv/collectionista/ics-main/view/head:/collectionista-library/src/net/lp/collectionista/util/FragmentListActivity.java) at my code, but it's always best to derive the latest.

Same goes for `GridActivity` I would say.

Comment: And what shall we do with the `com.android.internal.R` references?

Comment: Brian, is that for the ListActivity class? I didn't come across any. Hope they didn't b0rk this in 4.2 going forward?

Comment: well there were three of them. I came up with a solution that works for me so far. See: https://gist.github.com/4201753


btw: *upvote* there you go :)

Comment: Were they just resolvable as android.R then? Could be, don't remember.  I should've shared my code too, here goes: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~pjv/collectionista/ics-main/view/head:/collectionista-library/src/net/lp/collectionista/util/FragmentListActivity.java

Comment: I replaced them to android.R.* Except for one: android.R.layout.list_content didn't work for me, so I extracted it to a abstract `getSupportLayoutResourceId()`. This works as long as I call `setContentView(getSupportLayoutResourceId())`

Comment: Apparently it did for me, because that's what I have in my code: android.R.layout.list_content

Answer (score 1):

Look at this question:
[What to do about ListActivity/MapActivity when converting to Fragments using the compatibility library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497121/what-to-do-about-listactivity-mapactivity-when-converting-to-fragments-using-the)

There is a **ListFragment**.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can create the Fragment ListActivity with compatibility with viewpager package v4

Here is the [example](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/542)

another [example](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/)

Comment: Those are ViewPager tutorials

Comment: but in view pager i used the fragment activity my it will be helpful to you thanks