# Two different extend on class

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I'm really new to android, so sorry for this question I guess.

I started making an application with the standard tab swipe navigation. It works with four different fragments. I'm trying to give content to these four fragments.

In one of the four fragments I want a library sort of thingy. As simple as: when you click on an item it goes to a detailed content page. The easiest way to accomplice this seems to be this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/ + sending extra data (content for the detailed page) to the new activity.

In this tutorial I need to extend the class with ListActivity. The problem is my fragment activity allready is extended with Fragment. So my question is can I even use the code in a fragment or maybe is there a way around this? Or maybe I am doing something completely wrong....

Fragment code:

```
  import com.example.airassist.R;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;

  public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

And this is from the maincode where it switches fragments

```
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            //  fragment activity
            return new HomeFragment();
        case 1:
            // fragment activity
            return new HerrinerFragment();
        case 2:
            // fragment activity
            return new TestFragment();
        case 3:
            // fragment activity
            return new BiblioFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Couple of errors with ListFragment:

```
   11-13 09:24:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(786): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   11-13 09:24:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(786): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list  
   11-13 09:24:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(786):   at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
   11-13 09:24:15.648: E/AndroidRuntime(786):   at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
```

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Look into extending `ListFragment` instead of `Fragment`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497121/what-to-do-about-listactivity-mapactivity-when-converting-to-fragments-using-the

Comment: Also worth looking at is having a ListView control on your fragment and writing a custom Adapter for it.

Comment: Well the tab swipe is purely a navigation bar right? And it works with fragments. In one of the fragments I want a ListView where you click on an item it goes to a content page with information about that item. I found a tutorial on how to do that. But I can't implement it 'right' in my fragment activity.

Comment: So I tried simply editing extends Fragment into extends ListFragment. I get a lot of errors. I updated the OP with a couple of those errors.

Comment: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list : your content is the view object your are returning in onCreateView. So you have to open the layout and put inside it a ListView with id @android:id/list